# how to properly create an android app with opencv

Tags: python, android, opencv, qr-code

I have created several applications in python on a Windows PC. the applications for EAN code distribution work without any problem. After copying for android app does not work. ADB writes

ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

I have implemented most of the advice about reinstalling opencv.

Thanks

tested on several freely available codes. none works.